# Element depends upon value in previous element (shape, circle, rectangle)

Tags: xml

I am trying to write xml code for an element shape.
The shape must have a type, and depending on the type:
rectangle - must have height and width
circle - must have radius
but the code will not validate:

*Attribute name "rectangle" associated with an element type "type" must be followed by the ' = ' character.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE shape [
<!ELEMENT shape (color, type)>
<!ELEMENT color ANY>
<!ELEMENT type (rectangle | circle)>
<!ATTLIST type
    circle CDATA #IMPLIED
    rectangle CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT rectangle (height, width)>
    <!ELEMENT height ANY>
    <!ELEMENT width ANY>
<!ELEMENT circle (radius)>
    <!ELEMENT radius ANY>
]>
<shape>
    <color>red</color>
    <type rectangle>
        <rectangle>
            <height>10</height>
            <width>20</width>
        </rectangle>
    </type>
    <type circle>
        <circle>
            <radius>5</radiust>
        </circle>
    </type>
</shape>
```

Thank you.

Comment: <type rectangle>
is to specify an attribute so it is expecting <type rectangle="Something">  You can fix it by using <type category="rectangle">

Comment: @Sorceri if I have <type category="rectangle"> then this is another element to be defined eg. <!ELEMENT type (category)> ?

Comment: it would be an attribute and added to the !Attlist so you would remove circle CDATA #IMPLIED and rectangle CDATA #IMPLIED and add type category CDATA #IMPLIED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that

```
<type circle>
```

means circle is an attribute and you didnt define what the attribute was. A fix defining a category as an attribute and using rectangle and circle as the values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE shape [
<!ELEMENT shape (color, type)>
<!ELEMENT color ANY>
<!ELEMENT type (rectangle | circle)>
<!ATTLIST type
    category CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT rectangle (height, width)>
    <!ELEMENT height ANY>
    <!ELEMENT width ANY>
<!ELEMENT circle (radius)>
    <!ELEMENT radius ANY>
]>
<shape>
    <color>red</color>
    <type category="rectangle">
        <rectangle>
            <height>10</height>
            <width>20</width>
        </rectangle>
    </type>
    <type category="circle">
        <circle>
            <radius>5</radiust>
        </circle>
    </type>
</shape>
```

or optionally if you leave it the way you have it; just give them values

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE shape [
<!ELEMENT shape (color, type)>
<!ELEMENT color ANY>
<!ELEMENT type (rectangle | circle)>
<!ATTLIST type
    circle CDATA #IMPLIED
    rectangle CDATA #IMPLIED
>
<!ELEMENT rectangle (height, width)>
    <!ELEMENT height ANY>
    <!ELEMENT width ANY>
<!ELEMENT circle (radius)>
    <!ELEMENT radius ANY>
]>
<shape>
    <color>red</color>
    <type rectangle="I have four sides">
        <rectangle>
            <height>10</height>
            <width>20</width>
        </rectangle>
    </type>
    <type circle="I am round">
        <circle>
            <radius>5</radiust>
        </circle>
    </type>
</shape>
```